# Expanded Spell Slots

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock

What exactly are Expanded Spell Slots. Do they effect spells known? I'm very new to D&D, and I am unsure what it means. I did look in the PHB, and found this:

> The Warlock table shows how many spell slots you have. The table also
> shows what the level of those slots is; all of your spell slots are
> the same level. To cast one of your warlock spells of 1st level or
> higher, you must expend a spell slot. You regain all expended spell
> slots when you finish a short or long rest.
>
> For example, when you are
> 5th level, you have two 3rd-level spell slots. To cast the 1st-level
> spell *thunderwave*, you must spend one of those slots, and you cast it
> as a 3rd-level spell.

Comment: That bad OCR though….

Comment: Yup. It is very very terrible.

Comment: Please buy the real book. Don't rip it off some internet page.

Comment: A fair  amount of the basic rules information is [here at the SRD_V_5.1 from Wizards of the Coast's web site](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf). It is free, but it does not have all of the  material in the PHB.  I recommend getting the PHB.

Answer (score 10):

It's expended, not expanded. Expended means it is used up.

Lets say you have one spell slot, it is  level one because you picked warlock.

You use one casting a level one spell.

You can't use that one anymore because it is used up, until you take a short or long rest.

So till then, you can only use cantrips.

Comment: Thank you. Feel kind of dumbfounded because of my misreading.

Comment: @TheLeviathan It's fine. We all do it. It should be noted that spell casting for warlocks is very weird and not really spellcasting, but for a quick tid bit and without going into crazy amounts of detail just know that warlocks have strange spell slots compared to wizards and other classes.

Comment: Weird how?  Warlock's cast spells the same as everyone else.  The only difference is that they regain their spell slots on a short rest and only have one level of spell slots instead of several.  If anything Warlock spell casting is much simpler than other classes.

Comment: @JBC what Jihelu is saying is Warkocks have *Pact Magic* which is an ENTIRELY different feature than the feature called *Spellcasting* that every other magical class obtains. Though some mechanics and terms are the same, it is intentially a different feature.

Comment: Despite the fact that it's completely different, you can use Warlock spell slots to cast other class spells if you multi-class and your other spell casting class slots to cast Warlock spells. PHB pg. 164.

Comment: It's different from a flavor perspective, but not a mechanical perspective.  There are many RP aspects that surround the difference, sure.  Consider, however, that Sorcerers magic comes innately, while Wizard magic comes from learning, while Cleric magic is performed via their Deity, and so forth.  All the magics are different flavors, but mechanically they all work the same.  As I recall, the specific reason for Warlocks having differently-named casting simply comes down to facilitating the separation of spell slot progression.

Comment: @JBC I don't mean to be rude but it IS different from a mechanical perspective. Especially if you look at multiclassing and how spell slots are obtained.

Comment: I already pointed that out...

Comment: "It's different from a flavor perspective, but not a mechanical perspective. "... That's obviously mechanical. I'm not talking "Warlocks get very little spellslots per level". I'm talking about how warlock levels don't add up with other magick classes when deciding spell slots for the purpose of multiclassing. Which is a huge mechanical difference.